# Seperate network connection on server with 2 NICs

Tags: linux, firewall, routing, centos7, vlan

This is the setup we are aiming for in the picture.
As you can see, the supervisor server (CentOS 7.5) has two physical nics (eth0, eth1).

[image: Network Concept Diagram]

One of the design goals would be, to have eth0 allowed to communicate to the client network only and eth1 to the render network only.

What would be the best practice here?

Comment: Why do you not just configure VLAN tags 10, 11, 12, 50, and 60 on the links all the way to the supervisor?

Comment: To clarify your proposal:
- switch-port of eth0: configure VLAN10,11,12
- switch-port of eth1: configure VLAN50,60

Correct?

Comment: Why would that be a design goal? A better design goal would be to make sure your network is redundant in case a link or a switch fails. This would result in both NICs being able to access all other devices.

Comment: @Tom: It's a recommendation from the developers of our render management software. I think the reason for this is to guarantee that traffic between  supervisor and clients/workers is properly detached.
Of course, all uplinks are already redundant, I was just lazy on the diagram because my question focuses on how I can implement the proposal from the devs.

Answer (score 0):

After I tried my luck with static routes and policy based routing I figured that it was getting way to hacky. A colleague brought me to remember vlan-interfaces and the use of DNS records in subdomains.

This is the solution I came up with. It works like a charm and does exactly what I wanted to achieve:

[image]